# Vagrant can't up VirtualBox - entered invalid state

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualization

Trying to up a Zesty 32-bit guest machine on a Xenial 64-Bit host, but it shows an invalid stated erroron Vagrant. The same machine fires okay when running into VirtualBox.

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

The Machine Log in Virtualbox is [here](https://pastebin.com/aafL1RGA).

Vagrant 1.9.1.... Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

There are few possibility to resolve the issus. According to the description, it is not vagrant problem and something to do with virtual box. Follow the step , may be one of the step will be your solution.

1. Check your BIOS, is it your VT-X features enabled ? if not please enable it and try 'vagrant up again'.
2. If you are in windows 8 , you may want to remove Hyper-V and try
3. If your virtual box not in latest version, please update and try
4. While you trying vahgrant up, also open your virtual box to see if the box is opening, if stuck in login, you need to login manually , sometimes it works.
5. You might want to try winth new instance.

Try and see if that helps